# MS Access Select Multiple Joins

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, join

I'm trying to select by c# and odbc from the following tables.

```
LinkTab (FromDevID, FromPort, ToDevID, ToPort)
DevList (ID,DevName...)
```

The result should look like

```
FromDevName  | FromPort | ToDevName | ToDevPort
```

i tried already the following statement:

```
SELECT dev1.DevName, lt.FromPort, dev2.DevName, lt.ToPort 
FROM (LinkTab lt
INNER JOIN DevList dev1 ON lt.FromDevID = dev1.ID) 
INNER JOIN devList dev2 ON lt.ToDevID = dev2.ID
```

and I couldn't get all records. I guess there is a mistake at my join condition.

Comment: you're doing `inner` join, which only returns records that match on BOTH sides of the join. if the `dev1` join produces a different number of records than the `dev2`, those will be suppressed.

Comment: @MarcB which join should i use then?

Comment: `left` or `right`, or `full outer`, perhaps.

Comment: The table names in your description don't match your SQL. -- If both `FromDevID` and `ToDevID` can be NULL, you need two left joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you need `left join`:

```
SELECT dev1.DevName, lt.FromPort, dev2.DevName, lt.ToPort 
FROM (LinkTab lt LEFT JOIN 
      DevList dev1
      ON lt.FromDevID = dev1.ID
     ) LEFT JOIN
     devList dev2
     ON lt.ToDevID = dev2.ID;
```

The reason your query would not return all the rows is because the devises may not always match.  If this is the case, then `INNER JOIN` will filter out the rows with unmatched devices.  A `LEFT JOIN` will keep all the rows in the first table, assigning `NULL` for the columns from the second and third tables.